# How to scrape multiple divs?

Tags: php, web-scraping, scrape, scraper

Hello I've got a bunch of divs I'm trying to scrape the content values from and I've managed to successfully pull out one of the values, result! However I've hit a brick wall, I want to now pull out the one after it inside the current code I've done. Hit a brick wall here would appreciate any help.

Here is the bit of code i'm currently using.

```
foreach ($arr as &$value) {

    $file = $DOCUMENT_ROOT. $value;
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTMLFile($file);
    $xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
    $elements = $xpath->query("//*[contains(@class, 'covGroupBoxContent')]//div[3]//div[2]");

    if (!is_null($elements)) {
      foreach ($elements as $element) {

        $nodes = $element->childNodes;
            foreach ($nodes as $node) {
                $maps = $node->nodeValue;

                echo $maps;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I simply want them all to have separate outputs that I can echo out.

Comment: Please show your div structure as well

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you use [Simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/). Beyond that I need to see a sample of the HTML you are scraping.

If you are scraping a website outside your domain I'd recommend saving the source HTML to a file for review and testing. Some websites combat scraping, thus what you see in the browser is not what your scraper would see.

Also, I'd recommend setting a random user agent via ini_set(). If you need a function for this I have one.

```
<?php
$html = file_get_html($url);
IF ($html) {
  $myfile = fopen("testing.html", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
  fwrite($myfile, $html);
  fclose($myfile);
}
?>
```